# use setState Hook to update previous value based on a set of conditions in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I want to use setState Hook to update the previous value based on a given condition. Here is how it should update:

```
const [ButtonTextIndex,changeButtonText] = useState(0);
changeButtonText(prev=>{
            if(prev===1)
            prev=0;
            else if(prev===0)
            prev=-1;
            else if(prev===-1)
            prev=1;
            else
            prev=2;
        });
```

I want to update prev value based on several if conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
changeButtonText(prev => {
        if(prev===1)
        return 0;
        else if(prev===0)
        return -1;
        else if(prev===-1)
        return 1;
        else
        return 2;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

ok this easy you can use javascript Ternary operator to return the value to set state hook like this:

```
const [ButtonTextIndex,changeButtonText] = useState(0);
changeButtonText(prev=>(prev===1?0:prev===0?-1:prev===-1?1:2));
```